# Detecting a request to foreground a suspended window

Tags: c#, windows-10

Is there a  way to detect a request foreground a window in c#? What I'm trying to do is to suspend a process (not the process doing the detecting) when the user switches their focus to another window, and then resume the process when they switch back.

I managed to detect when the user switches their focus away, but since the process is suspended, I don't know how to detect if they try to switch back.

Edit: I wrote process 1 which is the process doing the detecting and suspending

Process 2 is the external process that I'm detecting whether the user has focus on it or not (from process 1). If the user switches their focus from process 2, suspend process 2. And when they switch back, resume it (from process 1). What I don't know is how to detect if the user attwmpts to switches back if process 2 is suspended.

Comment: I thought the process doing the detecting was not the suspended process

Comment: "I managed to detect when the user switches their focus away, but since the process is suspended, I don't know how to detect if they try to switch back." not clear what is doing the detecting. If it is your suspended application, what kind of application is it? Winforms? WPF? Console?

Comment: @o_weisman the suspended process is not mine, I have a process that is mine which is suspending another process when the user switches their focus from the process that is being suspended (which is not mine)

Comment: @Prime_Aqasix did you ever figure this out? I have the same situation where I want to suspend a third-party process when not focused.

Comment: I've also run into the same situation. I used AccEvent (Windows SDK) to watch to see if there were any events emitted. You do get OBJ_FOCUS if the window is alt-tabbed to, but not from clicking it on the taskbar.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the monitored application's framework, you may be able to get focus change events for it by using UI Automation, something like (copied from MSDN):

```
`AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler focusHandler = null;

/// <summary>
/// Create an event handler and register it.
/// </summary>
public void SubscribeToFocusChange()
{
    focusHandler = new AutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(OnFocusChange);
    Automation.AddAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(focusHandler);
}

/// <summary>
/// Handle the event.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="src">Object that raised the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">Event arguments.</param>
private void OnFocusChange(object src, AutomationFocusChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // TODO Add event handling code.
    // The arguments tell you which elements have lost and received focus.
    System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement element = src as System.Windows.Automation.AutomationElement;
    if(element.Current.ProcessId == "MontioredApplicationProcessId")
    {
        //Monitored application has focus!
    }
    else
        //Monitored application does not have focus
}

/// <summary>
/// Cancel subscription to the event.
/// </summary>
public void UnsubscribeFocusChange()
{
    if (focusHandler != null)
    {
        Automation.RemoveAutomationFocusChangedEventHandler(focusHandler);
    }
}`
```